# How to create thumbnail from swf games?

Tags: php, flash, ffmpeg, thumbnails

I know there is way of creating thumbnail from swf video files using ffmpeg to take snapshot, but is there any way out there to create thumbnail from swf games files?

Answer (score 1):

No.

How would you programmatically determine the necessary key-presses to get to the part you want to capture? Intros, splash screens, main menu, keyboard/mouse controls, buttons in different locations doing different things... Too many variables to automate such a task; Each game is different.

It's simple enough to find an embedded video file in the swf container, but a "game" is a complex interaction of animated objects.